# Communicate beween AngularJs filter() to AngularJs directive()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
.filter('projectTeamPhotos', function($compile) {
    return function(teams, element) {
        if (teams.length == 0) {
            return '';
        }
        var el = pageUrl; /* pageUrl global variable */
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
            var url = el + 'files/image/' + teams[i].User.image;
            var link = el + '#/employee/view-details/' + teams[i].User.unique_id;
            var name = teams[i].User.name;            
            html += '<a href="' + link + '" title="' + name + '"><img check-image alt="image" class ="img-circle" src="' + url + '" /></a>';
        }
        return html;
    };
}).directive('checkImage', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('ngSrc', function(ngSrc) {
                $http.get(ngSrc).success(function() {
                    alert('image exist');
                }).error(function() {
                    alert('image not exist');
                    element.attr('src', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg'); // set default image
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<td ng-bind-html="project.ProjectTeam | projectTeamPhotos"></td>
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Here I have posted my `filter` and `directive` code. I want to access `checkImage` directive in my `projectTeamPhotos` filter.

I have called `check-image` directive in my image tag which content in the `projectTeamPhotos` filter. But my `check-image` directive not working. Please help me and say me how to access my directive in my filter?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/chinmay235/oas9xmax/1/)

Comment: why do you have `src` along with directive use, should it be `ng-src`?

Comment: @tanmay No I have not used ng-src.

Comment: I just changed that. ng-src also not working.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/plunker out of it?

Comment: Ok give me some time.

Comment: @tanmay I have created jsfiddle can you please check. https://jsfiddle.net/chinmay235/oas9xmax/1/

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. You're misusing a filter. It should be a directive instead.

Comment: you should be using `ng-repeat` to generate the HTML you have written in that loop inside `filter` and then, your `checkImage` directive would work normally

Comment: How I generate html by using ng-repeat within the filter?